# How to write dictionary values to a csv file using Python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a dictionary of class objects. I want to write the member values (timepoints, fitted, measured) of the class to a csv file using Python.

**My Class:**

```
class PlotReadingCurves:
    def __init__(self, timepoints, fitted, measured):
        self.timepoints = timepoints
        self.fitted = fitted
        self.measured = measured

obj = PlotReadingCurves(mTimePoints,mFitted,mMeasured)
PlotReadingCurvesList[csoId] = obj

Eg: timpoints : 1 2 3 4 5
    fitted: 6 7 8 9 10
    measured: 11 12 13 14
```

**Expected results:**

```
timepoints  fitted  measured     fitted      measured 
1              6      11          ..         ..
2              7      12         
3              8      13
4              9      14
5              10     15
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my mini wrapper library `pyexcel`. Although it is not as powerful as pandas, it is sufficient to write a dict to an excel file in a few lines of code:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> your_dict = { "timepoints": [1,2,3], "fitted":[6,7,8]} # more columns omitted
>>> sheet = pe.Sheet(pe.utils.dict_to_array(your_dict))
>>> sheet.save_as("your_file_name.csv") # done
```

With `pyexcel`, you can easily write your data into other excel formats: xls, xlsx and even ods. The documentation can be found [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/), here is pandas's feature about your problem.

Tools for reading and writing data between in-memory data structures and different formats: CSV and text files, Microsoft Excel, SQL databases, and the fast HDF5 format;

It's very convenient and powerful.